# OData is removing my existing parameters in Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to use Swagger with existing parameters. Adding in ODataQueryOptions removes All my other parameters in Swagger. How can I fix this to see my parameters? Code is below:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{rollType}/{assessmentYear}/{lkAssessmentStatus}/{eventId?}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PageResult<BasicAssessmentDetailsDto>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PageResult<BasicAssessmentDetailsDto>), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public ActionResult GetBasicPropertyAssessments(
    int rollType,
    int assessmentYear,
    int lkAssessmentStatus,
    int? eventId,
    ODataQueryOptions<BasicAssessmentDetailsDto> queryOptions)
{
    var result = assessmentRollService.GetBasicPropertyAssessmentsQueryable(rollType, assessmentYear, lkAssessmentStatus, eventId).ToODataPageResult(queryOptions);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

We added the following in Startup, and yet is still not working:

```
services.AddOData();
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    foreach (var outputFormatter in options.OutputFormatters.OfType<ODataOutputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
    {
        outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
    }
    foreach (var inputFormatter in options.InputFormatters.OfType<ODataInputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
    {
        inputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
    }
}
```

Add the following to Configure method

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
    endpoints.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(1000).Count();
});

namespace Common.OData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class allows us to add OData to our endpoints in swagger.
    /// </summary>
    public class ODataParametersSwaggerDefinition : IOperationFilter
    {
        private static readonly Type QueryableType = typeof(IQueryable);

        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var parameterDescriptions = context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions;
            foreach (var parameter in parameterDescriptions)
            {
                // identify if any of the response types of the end point
                // return a queryable type.
                if (parameter.Type == typeof(ODataQueryOptions) || parameter.Type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ODataQueryOptions)))
                {
                    // the schema of our new parameter (string)
                    var schema = new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string" };

                    operation.Parameters.Clear();

                    // $filter
                    operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
                    {
                        Name = "$filter",
                        Description = "Filter the results using OData syntax.",
                        Required = false, // these are all optional filters, so false.
                        In = ParameterLocation.Query, //specify to pass the parameter in the query
                        Schema = schema
                    });

                    // $orderby
                    operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
                    {
                        Name = "$orderby",
                        Description = "Order the results using OData syntax",
                        Required = false,
                        In = ParameterLocation.Query,
                        Schema = schema
                    });

                    // $skip
                    operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
                    {
                        Name = "$skip",
                        Description = "Skip the specified number of entries",
                        Required = false,
                        In = ParameterLocation.Query,
                        Schema = schema
                    });

                    // $top
                    operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
                    {
                        Name = "$top",
                        Description = "Get the top x number of records",
                        Required = false,
                        In = ParameterLocation.Query,
                        Schema = schema
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

We do not see additional parameters

[image]

Currently using Net Core 3.1

Comment: You have ``operation.Parameters.Clear();`` line here. Can it be the reason?

Comment: My experience with .NET Framework 4.x (not on Core) was that I never needed to add those $filter, etc parameters manually for my ODataControllers.  Maybe something in the way you are registering your ODataRoute or ApiExplorer is not quite right?  Can you add your relevant parts of startup.cs?

Comment: Would you please try this: ? keep your method as HttpGet but call it with Post method.